# Есть ли класс wrapper для bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Есть ли в bootstrap обертка (wrapper) для странички(HTML)?
Может быть неправильно задал вопрос, но мне нужно сделать общий padding для странички.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. У бутстрапа нет общей обертки.
2. Если вы хотите задать вертикальный внутренний отступ, то спокойно можете добавить его к body.
3. Если вы хотите задать горизонтальный отступ:

a) Если вы планируете сделать отступ больше чем половина `gutter`, то можете просто добавить эти отступы для `container`. В 4 бутстрапе только для отступов есть отдельные классы. Таким образом вы можете обойтись только средствами бутсрап:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container pl-5 pr-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <span>1 of 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <span>2 of 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <span>1 of 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <span>2 of 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <span>3 of 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

б) Можно поменять в переменных основной отступ - тогда изменятся паддинги у контейнера, маргины у `row`, и паддинги у `col` и соответсвенно изменится отступ между колонками. В третьем бустрапе для этого можно воспользоваться [кастомизатором](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/).

в) Если вы планируете сделать отступ меньше чем половина `gutter` и оставить прежнее расстояние между колонками, тогда можно обернуть содержимое во wrapper c отрицательным оступом и добавить странице горизонтальный `overflow`, тогда следует помнить, что содержимое может обрезаться и чуть внимательнее относитесь к этому при тестировании.

г) Так же в бустрапе есть возможность делать колонки без отступа .no-gutter - тогда ваши паддинги у контейнера могут быть любой ширины.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по поиску его там нет, вы это можете проверить простым поиском в файлах `bootstrap`. Остаётся только создать самому.

Comment: Т.е. посоветуете для каждой секции делать внутренний margin? на примере наглядниее спрошу: .container. > . row >  .(мой класс с margin left/right ) > .col-md- 4 +  .col-md- 8.